# How to save a custom transformer in sklearn?

Tags: python, session, scikit-learn, pickle

I am not able to load an instance of a custom transformer saved using either `sklearn.externals.joblib.dump` or `pickle.dump` because the original definition of the custom transformer is missing from the current python session.

Suppose in one python session, I define, create and save a custom transformer, it can also be loaded in the same session:

```
from sklearn.base import TransformerMixin
from sklearn.base import BaseEstimator
from sklearn.externals import joblib

class CustomTransformer(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def fit(self, X, y=None):
        return self

    def transform(self, X, y=None):
        return X


custom_transformer = CustomTransformer()    
joblib.dump(custom_transformer, 'custom_transformer.pkl')

loaded_custom_transformer = joblib.load('custom_transformer.pkl')
```

Opening up a new python session and loading from 'custom_transformer.pkl'

```
from sklearn.externals import joblib

joblib.load('custom_transformer.pkl')
```

raises the following exception:

```
AttributeError: module '__main__' has no attribute 'CustomTransformer'
```

The same thing is observed if `joblib` is replaced with `pickle`.  Saving the custom transformer in one session with

```
with open('custom_transformer_pickle.pkl', 'wb') as f:
    pickle.dump(custom_transformer, f, -1)
```

and loading it in another:

```
with open('custom_transformer_pickle.pkl', 'rb') as f:
    loaded_custom_transformer_pickle = pickle.load(f)
```

raises the same exception.

In the above, if `CustomTransformer` is replaced with, say, `sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler`, then it is found that the saved instance can be loaded in a new python session.

Is it possible to be able to save a custom transformer and load it later somewhere else?

Answer (score 7):

`sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler` works because the class definition is available in the sklearn package installation, which `joblib` will look up when you load the pickle.

You'll have to make your `CustomTransformer` class available in the new session, either by re-defining or importing it.

Comment: But the `pickle` module also works for the `StandardScaler`, and surely it doesn't know about StandardScaler's definition?

Comment: `pickle` and `joblib` work the same way in this regard. Import information is stored with the pickled object, which is why you can screw things up when you unpickle an object made with a different version of a module than the one that's currently installed.

Comment: re-importing doesn't seem to work in my case, where I'm importing a custom FeatureUnion subclass.

Answer (score 2):

It works for me if I pass my transform function in `sklearn.preprocessing.FunctionTranformer()` and if I save the model using `dill.dump()` and `dill.load` a ".pk" file.

Note: I have included the tranform function into a sklearn pipeline with my classifier.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't use the `sklearn.externals.joblib` but just `joblib` module, It works:

example:

```
from sklearn.base import BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin

class CustomNgramVectorize(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):
    """Vectorizes texts as n-gram vectors"""
    def __init__(self, text, reduce=True):
        # Create keyword arguments to pass to the 'tf-idf' vectorizer.
        kwargs = {
                'ngram_range': NGRAM_RANGE,  # Use 1-grams + 2-grams.
                'dtype': 'int32',
                'strip_accents': 'unicode',
                'decode_error': 'replace',
                'max_features' : 1000, #limit number of words
                'sublinear_tf': True, # Apply sublinear tf scaling
                'stop_words' : stopwords.words('french'),# drop french stopwords
                'analyzer': TOKEN_MODE,  # Split text into word tokens.
                'min_df': MIN_DOCUMENT_FREQUENCY,
        }
        self.tfidf_vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(**kwargs)
        self.reduce = reduce
        if self.reduce:
            self.svd = TruncatedSVD(n_components=25, n_iter=25, random_state=12)
    
    def fit(self, X, y=None):
        self.tfidf_vectorizer.fit(X)
            
    def transform(self, X, y=None):
        X = self.tfidf_vectorizer.transform(X)
        # convert to dataframe
        X_df = pd.DataFrame(X.toarray(), columns=sorted(self.tfidf_vectorizer.vocabulary_))
        if self.reduce:
            X_df = self.svd.fit_transform(X_df)
        return X_df
```

then save it just by using `joblib.dump` function :

```
# persist model
import joblib
joblib.dump(vectorizer, 'custom_tfidf_vectorizer.joblib')
```

Later retrieve it with `joblib.load` function:

```
var='route_of_administration'
v = joblib.load('custom_tfidf_vectorizer.joblib')
v.fit(train[var])
X_df = v.transform(train[var])
```

[image]

Comment: When you load in the same notebook where the dump is, it will work. However, when you try loading the vectorizer in another file, you will probably get the same error.

Comment: Actually I used this vectorizer in a fully deployed pipeline, and it uses the `joblib.load` to get the transformer