# NotFittedError when saving a scikit-learn model with a custom transformer in the pipeline and using it to predict in a different file

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pickle, pipeline, joblib

I am in the same situation as was presented in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46077793/how-to-save-a-custom-transformer-in-sklearn): I want to save a model pipeline (a `ColumnTransformer`) in which there are some custom transformers I created, to use it to predict in another file placed in a different folder.

I managed to import the model in the new file through joblib as explained in the question linked above, i.e. creating a file with the custom transformers inside and importing them. However, when I use the `predict()` method of the uploaded model, I get the following:

```
NotFittedError: This ColumnTransformer instance is not fitted yet. Call 'fit' with appropriate arguments before using this estimator.
```

This makes sense since my custom transformers are just taken from a "new file" and therefore are not fitted yet.

However I do not understand which would be the **best practice** to solve this issue. Is there a better way than refitting the model to the dataset?

I saw that in some answers someone was suggesting to use [cloudpickle](https://github.com/cloudpipe/cloudpickle), could it be an option?